# Extract text from cells marked by regions

Tags: r, text, unicode, text-mining, stringr

I don't know how else to describe this problem. I apologize for the most vague title ever.

this is what the data looks like

> [us]Deftek
> [jp]<U+306F><U+3061><U+307F><U+3064> (Honey)
> Hampern
> [jp]<U+3067><U+3055><U+3093><U+3068> (Descente)
> [jp]<U+5E73><U+30DC><U+30E0> (Hirabomb)
> [jp]<U+30A2><U+30AD><U+30E9> (Akira)
> Balls Out
> [jp]Teguru
> [jp]Melty

So the names Hampern and Balls Out extract just fine, but the others I cannot extract anything from.

```
library(httr)
library(tidyverse)
library(jsonlite)

fromJSON(rawToChar(GET("https://www.speedrun.com/api/v1/runs?game=o1y9wo6q&category=wkpoo02r&max=200")$content))$data %>% 
  select(players) %>% 
  unnest(players) %>% 
  select(name) %>% 
  mutate(name_extract = str_extract(name, "[A-Za-z]*")) %>% 
  na.omit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the `[us][jp]` part from the `name`.

```
library(httr)
library(dplyr)
library(jsonlite)

fromJSON(rawToChar(GET("https://www.speedrun.com/api/v1/runs?game=o1y9wo6q&category=wkpoo02r&max=200")$content))$data %>% 
   select(players) %>% 
   unnest(players) %>%
   select(name) %>% 
   mutate(name_extract = sub('\\[.*\\]', '', name)) %>%
   na.omit

#   name                    name_extract       
#   <chr>                   <chr>              
# 1 [us]Deftek              Deftek             
# 2 [jp]はちみつ (Honey)    はちみつ (Honey)   
# 3 Hampern                 Hampern            
# 4 [jp]でさんと (Descente) でさんと (Descente)
# 5 [jp]平ボム (Hirabomb)   平ボム (Hirabomb)  
# 6 [jp]アキラ (Akira)      アキラ (Akira)     
# 7 Balls Out               Balls Out          
# 8 [jp]Teguru              Teguru             
# 9 [jp]えるも (Erumo)      えるも (Erumo)     
#10 [jp]Melty               Melty              
# … with 88 more rows
```